# TideSDK: Change titlebar color and add fullscreen

Tags: background, fullscreen, titlebar, tidesdk

I wanted to change the color of titlebar from default silver to a dark grey (near black). The problem is: I couldn't find a way to create an Xcode project that either resembles TideSDK itself or integrates TideSDK in an existing application.

Adding to that I also want to add the native fullscreen button that exists since OS X Lion.

How can I either make these changes to the existing sdk shipped with my application or create a new Xcode (cocoa) application that uses TideSDK?